# Extract string and number combination from a larger string

Tags: java

I have a number of large strings looking like this:

```
"text(24), text_2(5), text_4(822)..."
```

I'm trying to check if a specific text exists and get the corresponding value.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Edit:

I have an array with all possible text values. At the moment I use foreach to check for text values.
I have the string text_2 and what I need is the corresponding 5 as an integer.

Comment: I think that regex will do the job https://www.javatpoint.com/java-regex

Comment: are you trying to do this once, or a number of times for the given string?

Comment: A number of times

Comment: Can the text contain "," or "()" ?

Comment: The text is always a word like views or user_inputs and only contains letters, numbers and _.

Comment: @Shaggy check out my updated answer, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to do this a number of times. I suggest you split the string and build a map from the text to its value, this is O(n). After that, your lookups are only O(1) if you use HashMap.

```
String text = "text(24), text_2(5), text_4(822)";

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

String[] split = text.split(", ");

for(String s:split){
    //search for the position of "(" and ")"
    int start = 0;
    int end = s.length()-1;
    while(s.charAt(start) != '(')
        start++;
    while(s.charAt(end) != ')')
        end--;
    //put string and matching value in the map
    map.put(s.substring(0, start), Integer.parseInt(s.substring(start+1, end)));
}

System.out.println(map);
```

I also ran some benchmarks for a string containing 10000 entries. And this approach was about 4 times faster than a regex approach. (38 ms vs 163 ms)

Comment: If performance if really important. You can apply a similar search approach to the first splitting step, but i shouldn't do more than a factor 2

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex` to extract all the `text` element from the String and store them into a `map`, e.g:

```
String s = "text(24), text_2(5), text_4(822)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]*(_)?[0-9]*\\([0-9]+\\))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
Map<String, Integer> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
while(matcher.find()){
    String[] tokens = matcher.group().split("(?=\\([0-9]+\\),?)");
    String key = tokens[0];
    Integer value = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].substring(1, tokens[1].length() - 1));
    valuesMap.put(key, value);
}
System.out.println(valuesMap);
```

Once done, you can call `valuesMap.get("test_2");` to get the corresponding value. This is how the above example works:

- It splits text into tokens containing `<text>(<Value)`
- It then splits each token again, into `text` and `value` and places these into a `Map`.

Comment: I think "text" and "text_2" are just examples. Might be better if it works with any String.

Comment: @ThijsSteel: not me. I've up-voted both your answer and this one. Nurzhan on the other hand...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ah okay, maybe it got up-voted and then un-up-voted. anyway :)

Comment: Yes, I initially up-voted you, then you were down-voted by someone else, then I retracted my vote due to a valid comment made, then you corrected your answer and I re-up-voted you.... etc..